# The color defined in palette is not the same as output in seaborn.violinplot()

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot, color-palette

I used parameter palette in seaborn.violinplot() to define custom color in the violinplot, here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", palette=['#5f82b5', '#D76364'], data=tips, split=True, inner='box')
ax.legend_.remove()
plt.show()
```

Here is my output:

[image]

However, the color in the figure of the hues are #6a84aa and #c87272 (by using color picker), which is not the same as my definition. I also found this problem in sns.barplot(). How to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html):

> saturation: float, optional
>
> Proportion of the original saturation to draw colors at. Large patches often look better with slightly desaturated colors, but set this to 1 if you want the plot colors to perfectly match the input color.